# How to import HTML files in dist folder?

Tags: html, node.js, express, webpack

In my development environment I give

```
res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname,'../Views/setpwd.html');
```

and it is working well in development environment.

But in production Views are not moving to dist folder even though I have added html loader in webpack. Could you guys please help me on this?

Thanks in advance

## Webpack config##

```
var path = require('path');
 var webpack=require('webpack');
 var nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
module.exports = {
     entry: './src/app.js',
     output: {
         path: path.resolve(__dirname,'dist'),
         filename: 'src/server.js',
     },
      target: 'node',
      externals: [nodeExternals()],
      module: {
         loaders: [{ test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader'}],
         loaders: [
            { test: /\.(html)$/, loader: "file" }
        ]
     },
     plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            compress: {
                warnings: false,
            },
            output: {
                comments: false,
            },
        }),
    ]
 }
```

deVdependencies

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.5.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.2",
    "webpack": "^2.6.1",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.6.0"
  },
```

Comment: Your configuration doesn't seem to read the environment or make any differentiation between dev and prod

Comment: "dev": "nodemon --debug src/app.js --exec babel-node --presets es2015",
    "start": "node dist/src/server.js"

I am using babel-cli for dev so I kept Webpack for prod

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding this correctly, you want to copy over the HTML files in `../Views/*.html` to a `dist/` directory using webpack. If so, then you need to use the [copy-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/kevlened/copy-webpack-plugin):

```
new CopyWebpackPlugin([
  {
    from: path.resolve(__dirname, '../path/to/views/directory'),
    to: path.resolve(__dirname, '../path/to/dist')
    ignore: ['.*']
  }
])
```

Comment: If my answer was correct then mark it as such please.